# Nodemailer not able to create transport / 502 error

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am having contiunual woes with getting nodemailer to send. I have now found the lowest security email account I can to see if I can get the thing working with a view to increasing security once something is getting through. My code is:

```html
app.post("/contact-us", function(req, res){
    var mailOpts, smtpTrans;
    
    smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
         host: 'smtp.123-reg.co.uk',
            port: 25,
            secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
            auth: {
                user: 'enquiries@*********.co.uk',
                pass: '**********'
            }
    });
    
    mailOpts = {
      from: "enquiries@*******.co.uk",
      to: "**********@mac.com",
      subject: 'Website contact form',
      text: "test email"
    };

  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, response) {
      //Email not sent
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.render('contact', { title: '********', msg: 'Error occured, message not sent.', err: true, page: 'contact-us' });
      }
      //Yay!! Email sent
      else {
          console.log("message sent");
          res.render('/');
      }
  });
});
```

Neither of the console.logs are coming back, instead the request is met with a timeout & 502 message,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone searches for this in the future; the problem was within cloud 9 which wouldn't allow access to the email account to prevent spam.